# According to Vedas, how to cook & eat sacrificed animal's meat?

Tags: vedas, worship, food, sacrifice

I know Tantric and Puranic traditions may be different, but how to cook & eat animals as per Vedas? [Rig Veda 10.28.3](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10028.htm):

> अद्रिणा ते मन्दिन इन्द्र तूयान सुन्वन्ति सोमान पिबसि तवमेशाम |पचन्ति ते वर्षभानत्सि तेषां पर्क्षेण यन्मघवन हूयमानः || or Bulls they **dress** for thee, and of these thou eatest when, Maghavan, with food thou art invited.

But I also found another translation which says it specifically mentions roasting:

> They **roast** bulls for you, you eat them when you are invoked, Maghavan, to the sacrificial food.

Is this accurate? Is any other method of cooking prescribed? If the above is not accurate then which **dressing** should we put on bull meat according to Vedas?

Is there any restriction in Vedas or can we make **biryaani, sandwiches, curry** or whatever we want and eat sacrificial meat however we want?